# PHP - Collapse a Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$result = Array
          (
              [0] => Array
                     (
                         [Product] => Array
                                      (
                                          [id] => 3
                                      )

                     )

          )
```

I have the above array, how do I collapse it so `$result = 3`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$result = $result[0]['Product']['id']; // TA DA
```

Comment: lol! I'll +1 this too. But I guess this is not the answer he was looking for.

Comment: @Neal What I want to know is why I can't get 8+ upvotes with such a question/answer...  It's a conspiracy!  On the real though it does feel like those with a higher rep get more votes/support then those who don't; which kind of sucks as I usually put a lot of effort into my answers and pretty thorough (not saying you or anyone else don't) even tackling questions others won't.  The most I ever get is +1 maybe +2 upvote.  Guess it's much like the real world where the rich get richer and the poor get poorer.  In any case </rant>

Comment: @JeffWilbert or write some quips like `TA DA` :-) that seemed to bring people in ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
$result = $result[0]['Product']['id']; // gives 3
```